# Whitespaces at the Process Arguments

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, command-line-arguments, whitespace

I am trying to create a Visual Studio Add-In by using Visual Studio 2015, VSIX project. The add-in should be able to run an .exe file along with current project path. Currently i can find the path of the project and give it as argument of the Process (the .exe file).
The .exe file is run by cmd as follows:

```
    the.exe -d projectDirectoryPath
```

Detecting the project path is not my problem but, if the path contains **Space Character** , it is understood as a seperate argument.
Following code is what i've used for starting the process:

```
string myDir = activeProjectPath();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.FileName = pathOfExe + "\\the.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "-d " + myDir;
```

The code works fine when the path of the current project does not contain **Space Character**, otherwise process can not started. The process gives following error:

> Given args:-d C:\Users\theUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\testProject\testProject
>
> Too many arguments specified in your command line! Skipping extra argument: Studio
>
> Too many arguments specified in your command line! Skipping extra argument: 2015\Projects\testProject\testProject

**Note:** When i try to run the.exe from cmd, it accepts space characters in the path of the projects.

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: put the path in quotes

Comment: windows poorly handles spaces.. frankly they should never have let it, because it decides c:\program files\something\my.exe is to be c:\program - oh doesnt exist and files\something\my.exe which also doesnt exist.. the quotes are essential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use " character. You can specify the path in the following form:
"C:\Users\foo\My Documents\file name.sln", for example.
You can surround any path with " character, like in batch or Powershell script.

startInfo.Arguments = string.Concat("-d ", "\"", myDir, "\"");